# What's the idiomatic way to politely propose an activity?

Tags: перевод

In English we have:

- Would you like do x?
- Should we do x?
- Let's do x

What would the idiomatic equivalent(s) in Russian be? 
For instance a literal translation of `should we go to work?` might be `мы должны встретиться после работы ?` (I used a translator here, my Russian isn't so good and Google is failing me on this issue.)

Even if this is *literally* correct, I doubt that it is idiomatic Russian, as in my experience, Russian phrases tend to be a little more direct/to the point.

A language learning site suggested:
`Я хотела бы пригласить тебя к себе на ужин.`
For `I would like to invite you to dinner at my place.`

Is that the same level of politeness as it sounds like it is in English?

Answer (score 3):

The common patterns for translation of such questions are:

> - [*Pronoun*] *verb* ... ?
> - [Не] *verb* [ли] *pronoun* ... ?

*Where optional parts are enclosed in brackets.*

For example, the following questions have the same meaning `Would you like to have a drink?`:

> Выпьем?
>   Хотите выпить?
>   Вы хотите выпить?
>   Не хотите выпить?
>   Вы не хотите выпить?
>   Не хотите ли выпить?
>   Не хотите ли вы выпить?

The first form is the most direct. The last one is the most politeness.
More words - more politeness. :)

---

So the Russian equivalents are:

- Would you like do x?

  > [Не] хотите [ли] x?
  >   [Вы] хотите x?
- Should we do x?

  > [Не] должны [ли] мы x?
  >   Мы должны X?

  Or

  > [Не] следует [ли] нам x?
  >   Нам следует x?
- Let's do x

  > Давайте сделаем х?
  >   Сделаем x?

---

The translations of

> Should we go to work?

are

> Мы должны идти на работу?
>   Не должны ли мы идти на работу?
>   *etc*

Comment: does Вы не хотите выпить? have the same connotations as "wouldn't you like a drink?" - there's a sense of escalation / enticement in that one.

Comment: @baordog I believe you are right, it does.

Answer (score -1):

Even more polite would be:

***Не хотели бы Вы выпить?***